# How to convert Scrapy script to .exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have two *.py file -- `scrap.py` and `get_urls.py`. First one has following structure:

```
import scrapy
import json
import os
from get_urls import get_urls
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class CataSpider(scrapy.Spider):

... # some scrapy code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 5,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.5,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': filename,
        "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
    },
    )
    c.crawl(CataSpider)
    c.start()
    input('Press ENTER to exit...')
```

Second file has just simple function to collect links using selenium chromedriver.

I want to create Windows executable that will launch this spider. I tried Auto-py-to-exe. But I get following error messages when scrapy tries to send request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks
StopIteration: <200 https://some.url>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 55, in mustbe_deferred
  File "scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 52, in _process_spider_input
  File "scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 149, in call_spider
  File "scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 246, in warn_on_generator_with_return_value
  File "scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 229, in is_generator_with_return_value
  File "inspect.py", line 997, in getsource
  File "inspect.py", line 979, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 798, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code
```

What can be done with this? Googling didn't help me much...